# NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/AcceptedW3CCapabilityKeys after upgrade to selenium 4

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-java

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/AcceptedW3CCapabilityKeys at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.lambda$checkNonW3CCapabilities
error after upgrading my selenium from 3.14 to Selenium 4.4

Step failed

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/openqa/selenium/AcceptedW3CCapabilityKeys

Here is my pom.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> ```

4.0.0

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <cucumber.options>--tags ${mtags}}</cucumber.options>
    <env>app</env>
    <threads>1</threads>
    <browser>chrome</browser>
    <GroupingScheam>FEATURE</GroupingScheam>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven/maven-plugin-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven/maven-project -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber6-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.28</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*CukesRunner.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectName>HE_HQ_Automaton</projectName>
                        <!-- output directory for the generated report -->
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                        <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</inputDirectory>
                        <jsonFiles>
                            <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                            <param>**/cucumber.json</param>
                        </jsonFiles>
                        <classificationFiles>
                            <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                            <param>sample.properties</param>
                            <param>other.properties</param>
                        </classificationFiles>
                        <!--<parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>-->
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You have so much unnecessary stuff in your pom. You will not be able to find the problem unless you clean up your project. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I just updated my post for more readably purpose.